# Django routing POST deletion request to viewProduct?

Tags: python, django

When I try to delete a product on my django app, I get a 404 error stating:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/product/1/delete/
Raised by:  products.views.viewProduct

No Product matches the given query.
```

I'm confused as to why Django is routing the deletion request to viewProduct, since my urls.py clearly states that it should route to deleteProduct.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [

    path('new/', views.NewProduct, name='NewProduct'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/<str:slug>/', views.viewProduct, name='viewProduct'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/delete/', views.deleteProduct, name='deleteProduct'),

]
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Product
from django.utils import timezone
from slugify import slugify


def viewProduct(request, pk, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk = pk, slug = slug)
    return render(request, 'viewProduct.html', {'product' : product})


def deleteProduct(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        product = Product.objects.filter(pk = pk)   
        return redirect('viewProduct', pk = pk, slug = product.slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk = pk)
        if product.productAuthor == request.user:
            product.delete()
    return redirect('viewAll')
```

Deletion form:

```
{% if request.user == product.productAuthor %}
    <form action="/product/{{ product.pk }}/delete/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name="pk" class="btn btn-link text-danger" value="delete product">
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

If it helps you, I just recently changed the site to view posts by both ID and slug instead of just ID. Before I changed this, the deletion function worked perfectly.

Comment: Move this path('product/<int:pk>/delete/', views.deleteProduct, name='deleteProduct'), above the other entry. Probably an order of precedence issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is the way you indent after deletion, try this

I cannot see your viewAll url handler where you want to redirect, you need to write a viewAll view where you list all your products

```
from django.urls import reverse


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.ViewAll, name='viewAll')
    path('new/', views.NewProduct, name='NewProduct'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/<str:slug>/', views.viewProduct, name='viewProduct'),
    path('product/<int:pk>/delete/', views.deleteProduct, name='deleteProduct'),

]


def deleteProduct(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        product = Product.objects.filter(pk = pk)   
        return redirect('viewProduct', pk = pk, slug = product.slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk = pk)
        if product.productAuthor == request.user:
            product.delete()
            return redirect(reverse('yourappname:viewAll'))
```

Answer (score 0):

URL patterns are processed in order. "delete" is a perfectly valid value for a slug, so the view pattern is matched and its view called.

You could fix this by swapping the order of the URLs, so that "delete" is matched first.